# A question on rank of a difference of two skew-symmetric.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose we have two $(n+1)\times (n+1)$ skew symmetric matrices $B,B'$ how to show that: $rank(B-B') \equiv 0 \mod 2$?

It's stated without proof in parantheses on page 738 of "Principles of Algebraic Geometry" by Harris and Griffiths.
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by approximately equal to 0 mod 2??

Comment: Are there restrictions on $ n $?

Comment: My mistake, I mean $\equiv$.

Comment: @Bananach I don't see any further restrictions on $n$. I will update my post with a screenshot of the page.

Comment: @Bananach I updated my post with the pic from the book.

Comment: @JosuEtxezarretaMartinez I updated my post to include a pic from the book.

Answer (score 0):

Because $K=B-B'$ is real skew-symmetric.

EDIT. If $rank(K)=r$, then $K$ admits $n-r$ times the eigenvalue $0$; the other eigenvalues are couples in the form $i\alpha,-i\alpha$ where $\alpha >0$; consequently $r$ is even.

Sketch of the proof. 1.  $K$ is diagonalizable over $\mathbb{C}$.

2. If $Kx=\lambda x,x\not= 0$, then $<Kx,x>=<x,K^Tx>=-<x,Kx>$ implies $\bar{\lambda}||x||^2=-\lambda ||x||^2$.

Comment: So the diagonal entries are zero, how to continue from here?

Comment: This holds for any skew-symmetric matrix over any field. $\mathbb R$ is a red herring. See Keith Conrad, *Bilinear forms* ( http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/linmultialg/bilinearform.pdf ) , Theorem 5.1.